# GNUCash 4.8 not displaying reports

Tags: lubuntu, gnucash

I've just upgraded my OS from Ubuntu 16.04 to Lubuntu 22.04, and thus my GNUCash from 2.6.12 to 4.8. The data all comes up and can be worked with, and new entries made, but I can't get any report to display any information. I'm afraid I'm not very good at all this (it just worked before!), so if anyone has any fairly simple suggestions to help me get my reports displaying I'd love to hear them.

EDIT:
When I open GNUCash I see my accounts hierarchy, and I can open the various accounts, make new entries and change existing entries. However, when I open any report I get a blank page. When I open 'Options' on the report to try and get it to display something nothing is displayed, no matter what I select/deselect.

Answer (score 5):

I have had this problem since I recently installed an update to the nVidia driver.

Richard Ullger describes an issue between WebKitGTK 2.4.2 (used by GnuCash) and nVidia GPUs.
https://lists.gnucash.org/pipermail/gnucash-user/2023-October/109026.html

I found this answer by John Ralls for GnuCash flatpack distributions:
https://lists.gnucash.org/pipermail/gnucash-user/2023-October/109024.html

I'm not using a flatpack version but running:

```
WEBKIT_DISABLE_COMPOSITING_MODE=1 gnucash
```

fixes the issue on my Dell XPS 15 9500 laptop.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a Nvidia graphics card? You'll find information on this issue elsewhere, though I haven't personally found a fix for my blank reports yet. The problem boils down to the reports not displaying on-screen. All other functions work properly to my knowledge. Temporary workarounds are printing the report, sending to PDF, or what I've been doing, copy the GnuCash data and config files to a second machine not using Nvidia and work with reports there.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks for this Dave, I don't have a graphics card, I'm running off the integrated graphics on the motherboard.

Comment: I also found that you can right-click on the body of the "blank" report, where you may also notice your cursor change from an arrow to the text I-beam, do a Select All/Copy to display in Excel, LibreOffice Calc, Text, etc. While still not a direct solution, certainly more efficient for working with the report data in real-time than the process I described earlier. Thanks for the follow-up.

Comment: Thank you, Charlie Halliday! If I had sufficient reputation points I would mark your post as the answer. This just worked for me. I had seen the gnuCash post and had tried entering the "WEBKIT_DISABLE..." command several days ago but I must have mis-entered it because I only got a "Command Not Found" response. Otherwise I would have suggested it. I will use this in the future when I am working with reports